# asp.net: ListView on the masterpage

Tags: asp.net, listview, master-pages

I have some asp.net pages.

I used the masterpage to implement common control.

There is a listview on the masterpage.

And there is a label on the contentpage.

I want to implement below.

When user select a node on the listview of masterpage,

the label text on the contentpage is changed into the text of the node.

How can i implement this.

Could you give me some advice or some link about my question?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **Master1.master**, I used ItemCommand event on ListView

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ListView ID="List1" runat="server" onitemcommand="List1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p>
                <asp:label ID="ItemLabel" runat="server" text="<%#Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemLink" runat="server" CommandName="SelectItem" Text="Select" />
            </p>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</form>
```

And **Master1.master.cs**, store selected item text to public property

```
    public partial class Master1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {

        public string selectedText { get; set; }

        protected void List1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "SelectItem")
            {
                selectedText = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("ItemLabel")).Text;
            }
        }

   }
```

Then in **Content1.aspx** , add a label with id Label1

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
```

Finally in **Conetnt1.aspx.cs**, read the property "selectedText" on prerender event (which comes after select click)

```
 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myMaster = (Master1)this.Master;
        Label1.Text = myMaster.selectedText;
    }
```